# Angular 2 complains modelClass.doSomething is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In the `ngOnInit()` method, I am looking an object from cache, and then try to execute a method defined in the class of that object.

It looks like

```
ngOnInit() {
    let modelClass: ModelClass = cache.modelClass;
    modelClass.doSomething();
}
```

and the definition of the model class is like

```
export class ModelClass{
    constructor(
        public property: string
    ){}

   doSomething(){
       //doing something here
   }
}
```

But when the component is being loaded and its ngOnInit() method is being invoked, there is an error at the line of modelClass.doSomething() like
modelClass.doSomething is not a function.

So why is ModelClass' method did not recognized?

Comment: Try to log cache and log cache.modelClass. otherwise more information will be necessary

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that `cache.modelClass` is defined at that point?  It's possible that you're trying to call the method on a null object.

In typescript, declarations are public by default, so that method should be exposed for you to call.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `cache.modelClass` doesn't return an instance of `ModelClass` but something else. You can add a check like so:

```
let modelClass: ModelClass = cache.modelClass instanceof ModelClass ? cache.modelClass : new ModelClass();
```